# How can I remove merged commit logs?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

[image]

Blue line is `feature` branch, red line is `develop` branch.
As you can see, `develop` branch was merged middle of `feature` branch.
And develop branch's logs were all included in feature branch.
like below

```
8191985 [feature] log5
62e338b [feature] log4
713d596 [feature] log3
ba94b24 Merge branch 'develop' into feature
bd751e9 [develop] log2
bec7f92 [develop] log1
7beb908 [feature] log2
5c1d36d [feature] log1
```

How can I clean up the develop branch's logs?
They didn't work well when I did like below..(conflict has occurred)

```
> git checkout feature
> git rebase develop
```

What thing I have to consider?

Comment: Is it important to you to keep all the blue dots - i.e. maintain the all commits of feature branch? Or is it ok for you to squash it to a single feature commit

Comment: Can you describe in more details what you mean by "clean up" ? do you want to completely remove the commits of `develop` from `feature` ? to group together the commits of `feature` on top of `develop` ? ... ?

Comment: @LeGEC I'd like to remove develop's commit logs on my `feature -> develop` PR..

Comment: @JoonT : and does "removing the log" also mean "removing all the code that got integrated from develop" ?

Comment: @LeGEC Oh, sorry. I made you confused. I just want squash merge.

Comment: Worth noting: the red line *isn't* the `develop` branch, not any more. It's commits that are on *both* branches. In Git, commits are quite normally on many branches all at the same time: that's what `git merge` is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is what are you trying to achieve.

**keep all the commits on `feature` branch, only rebase them on top of `develop` branch**

In this case you did exactly right. You rebase `feature` branch on top of `develop` branch and you must resolve all conflicts.

**Squash `feature` branch on top of `develop` branch**

In this case you can avoid resolving conflicts by:

```
git checkout feature
git reset develop
git add .
git commit -m "All my feature changes squashed together"
```

Comment: I don't understand why I have to resolve all conflicts between develop..? Because develop branch has already been merge T.T(first solution)

Comment: I assume when you you merged develop to the feature branch - you had conflicts and resolved them. So now if you want to rebase the branch, you need to solve the same conflicts again

Comment: Yes, I did resolve them. But now there are more than that conflicts.. Maybe I did something wrong. I'm gonna solve it using your solution. Thanks!